# System.Exception at Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr() on WinCE 5.0

Tags: exception, compact-framework

For some reason this exception is thrown by OS, it happens at Dispose() method. No extra details provided.

My code is too long to post. Generally, what does this exception mean?

I use .net CF 2.0 on WinCE 5.0

Answer (score 2):

Option 1. UI Method / Property Access on Non-UI Thread (Check Control.InvokeRequired)
Option 2. Low Memory State and Unhandled BitMap / Image Problem (AGL)